# Which one is used TCP Reno or TCP Tahoe?

Tags: networking, congestion-control

In real time TCP connection which one of these congestion algorithm is implemented?
If this is not used, Please give me the details of what algorithm is used or any link to learn about it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Reno ist the successor of Tahoe, it is reasonable to assume that Reno is used, unless your implementation is a bit old.

While Tahoe *might* have slightly better behaviour in presence of congestion, Reno recovers **much** better. TCP does not know whether or not your application is "realtime", and it does not care. TCP is a reliable in-order stream, no more and no less. Slow recovery is a real problem whereas "realtime" is not.
TCP certainly tries to be "as realtime as it can be", but not at the expense of neglecting its guarantees. For that, we have UDP.

Insofar, using Tahoe over Reno when you have both available doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime applications rarely use tcp. But if TCP must be used, then I'd say that they'd use TCP Vegas for CA.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS of the TCP sender, Linux has switched to using Binary Increase Congestion Control , while MAC uses New Reno . Microsoft server 2008 uses Compound TCP